# passing variable from asp.net page to new page using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, client-side

The following is on my asp.net page written in c#.  Where someURL is asp.net string variable that contained a html link such as http:\www.somewebsite.com.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "openPage", "<script type='text/JavaScript'>var link1 = document.getElementById('<%=someURL.ClientID%>');window.open(link1);</script>");
```

The objective is when the above javascript executed it will open a new browser page with the url contained inside the someURL string (http:\www.somewebsite.com, etc.)

My problem was that it opens a blank page with nothing in the url.  And I think I know why... the someURL variable referenced inside the javascript code was not from the calling asp.net page.

Am I right?  Any suggestion on how to achieve my objective?

Thank you.

Comment: document.getElementById('http:\www.somewebsite.com') makes no sense. please explain what you think this is doing.

Comment: Now you pointed it out.  That won't do what I think it would.  But my original objective is to replace the asp.net's Response.Redirect(someURL) with javascript that will do the same but also open a new browser window instead of the same window as the asp.net's Response.Redirect does.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of the purpose of this. But the variable `link1` is a reference to a DOM element.

you need to get the text (depending on what type of control `someURL` is in your ASP page) value of that `DOM element` in order to pass it to the other script.

This is by no means elegant or recommended but will work

C# - in your codebehind page

```
public string nextURL = "http://yourdomain.com/yourpage.aspx"
```

ASP.NET - in your aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var myLink = '<%= nextURL %>';

  function newPage() {
    window.open(myLink);
  }

</script>
```

Comment: My original objective is to replace the asp.net's Response.Redirect(someURL) with javascript that will do the same but also open a new browser window instead of the same window as the asp.net's Response.Redirect does. Any suggestion?

Comment: he answered your question. you're passing the open() method a DOM element not a string.

Comment: While I was aware of the concept behind this.  I was looking for some specific syntax help. See my other comment for my final coding.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of those new learners, after a bit of struggle here is my final code that will do the job for me:

In my calling .cs file:

```
   protected String someURL;  //global variable

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "openPage", "<script type='text/JavaScript'>window.open(currentLinkURL);</script>");
```

In my .aspx file:

```
var currentLinkURL = '<% = someURL %>';  //currentLinkURL is a javascript variable
```

Comment: I got the help from this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553813/how-do-i-give-javascript-variables-data-from-asp-net-variables