# How I can use a other dateformat in my jQuery Datepicker?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker, date-format

I use a jquery datepicker in my ASP.NEt Application and I want if the User is from Spania or german I use a other dateformat.

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#txtAbwesenheitBis").datepicker();
    $("#format").change(function () {
        $("#txtAbwesenheitBis").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", $(this).val());
    });
});
```

How I can use a other dateformat? Or how I can use the german dateformat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) is a link where possible formatting options are shown. Just build required formatting string using description.

**Upd:**
To set a formatting string depending on lable value you may use something like this:

```
if($("#lbllanguagelabel").text() == "EN")
  { 
    $("#txtAbwesenheitBis").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 'en-format-string'); 
  } else {
   ...
 }
```

But note that if your lable has runat="server", its id on client side will not be the same as on server side, so you should use `$("#<%=lbllanguagelabel.ClientID %>").text()` or, what is much simpler, define some unique class for it:

```
<asp:lable id="lbllanguagelabel" runat="server" CssClass="languageLable"...
```

and JS:

```
if($(".languageLable").text() == "EN")
      { 
        $("#txtAbwesenheitBis").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 'en-format-string'); 
      } else {
       ...
     }
```

Comment: Hm. In many ways. If you have a dropdown to switch - just set formatting string as value of corresponding option and use `$("#format").change` just like you have it in code. Or you may use `registerstartupscript` and simply put a JS with some variable set to required format.

Comment: [For instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553813/how-do-i-give-javascript-variables-data-from-asp-net-variables) - similar question on SO

Comment: for example I use a asp:label for the case in JS. The ASP:label text is EN, can I use it in the JS Code for change the format? how this.     if((#"lbllanguagelabel.text") == "EN") { $(#format).chage...}else {...}

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#localization) describes how to localize the calendar.

Basically you just include the appropriate localization script, which you can download from the jQuery-ui web site, e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-de.js'></script>
```

and you don't need to specify the dateFormat parameter: the appropriate default will be set by the localization script.  To support multiple languages you can do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker-<% =MyLanguage %>.js'></script>
```

This solution gives you localized month and day names in the popup calendar, as well as a default date format that matches the selected culture.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$("#txtAbwesenheitBis").datepicker({ dateFormat :"dd.mm.yyy"});
```

for the german format

Comment: Setting dateFormat to `dd.mm.yy` (not `dd.mm.yyy`) will localize the date format but won't localize the popup calendar.

Comment: @Joe im just given the dateformat for the german standards only

Comment: `yyy` is not a valid API date format http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate