# passing variable to javascript function fails in asp:dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu, onchange

Currently I have a function called in the following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
getCities('<%=BusinessID %>');
</script>
```

This works without any problem, now I want to do the same on an onchange event in a asp:dropdownlist as following:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAddressSPC" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" AutoPostBack="False" onchange="javascript:getCities('<%=BusinessID %>');" Width="306px" CssClass="txt12NormalLeft" ToolTip="Select State|Province|County" />
```

But now the ASP.net variable isn't evaluated and is passed as <%=BusinessID %> instead of the value.

If I do the same code in a normal HTML select it isn't a problem. What am I missing here?

Comment: That puts the text <%=BusinessID %> inside the variable, I want to have the value of BusinessID in there, my function is in an external js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly at the server element tag.

You should do that somewhere in the code behind:

```
ddlAddressSPC.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:getCities('" + BusinessID + "');");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var currentBusinessIdString = '<%=BusinessID %>';

var currentBusinessId = parseInt(currentBusinessIdString);

getCities(currentBusinessId);

</script>
```

If this didn't help you, you may try some issues listed here : [How do I give JavaScript variables data from ASP.NET variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553813/how-do-i-give-javascript-variables-data-from-asp-net-variables)

Answer (score 1):

try like this

Remove this from markup

```
onchange="javascript:getCities('<%=BusinessID %>');"
```

and add in `page_load`

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

      ddlAddressSPC.Attributes.Add("onchange", "getCities('" + BusinessID + "')");
  }
```